# Are there targets where `va_end` does anything non-trivial?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

All versions of `varargs.h` and/or `stdarg.h` I've seen either define `va_end` as an empty macro or some opaque compiler-specific function that I guess doesn't do anything either. The rationale in the C standard states "some implementations might need it", but gives no more details.

When would there be a real need for a `va_end()`? Any examples of ABI that would require such, preferably with an explanation?

Comment: The question was closed as a near-duplicate on *when* `va_end` should be called. Not my question (I know it should be called always--just in case it does something non-trivial). I'm curious *what* ABI would require a non-trivial `va_end`.

Comment: The third answer in the duplicate explains an ABI that might require a non-empty implementation of `va_end`. The ABI doesn't actually specify how varargs are implemented. So the answer would be some implementation that stores the args not on the stack

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: Which is the "third answer"?  People can sort them differently.  But anyway, none of those answers actually do so, as far as I can tell.  greyfade vaguely says mixed stack/register ABIs "may be more complicated" but doesn't explain where `va_end` would be needed.   Maxim explains why x86-64 SysV needs `va_copy` but not `va_end`.  James Curran just says "on platforms which have less traditional schemes, it becomes necessary" without elaborating which platforms or why.  I am voting to reopen this.

Comment: I could imagine a "user space" implementation which doesn't have special compiler support, and that needs some variable amount of scratch space, but doesn't have access to VLAs or `alloca`.  It might be forced to get it from `malloc`, and then `va_end()` could do the `free()`.

Comment: Now that this is no longer a dupicate... where's the "original" question?

Answer (score 7):

Older versions of Fabrice Bellard's `tcc` implemented `va_start()` using `malloc()` and `va_end()` using `free()`: so failing to call `va_end()` would leak memory. See [here](https://github.com/LuaDist/tcc/blob/master/include/stdarg.h#L49). This is because it made `va_list` a pointer to a structure, and `malloc()`/`free()` (or technically compiler builtins for them) were used to allocate/free the structure. In newer versions of `tcc`, `va_list` is now a single-element array of a structure instead of a pointer, and hence `va_end()` is now effectively a no-op, like it normally is.

Comment: THat was insane implemetation :)

Answer (score -1):

C has been around for a long, long time and has many standards. These standards tend to give compilers some leeway, letting them implement their own padding/headers/etc. for performance and other reasons. I assume this was added because, as mentioned, "some compilers might need it." Though languages *try* to abstract their implementation details, some things - inevitably - slip through the cracks... Hope this was helpful =]